# Documentation common to two tags

Tags: discussion, documentation

What shall be done for documentation that is common for two tags?

For example, if we want to do a documentation that uses Perl to access Excel via an API, would it make sense to tag both `perl` and `excel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for API references to provide examples of use across a wide variety of languages and platforms. If the take-away is *here's how to use the API*, then it should go in `excel`. If it's *here's how to use Perl*, then it should go in `perl`.

I could write generic examples of interacting with RESTful services in a number of languages, and that would belong in those languages. Likewise, examples of *creating* RESTful services would belong in those languages.

But once you have a clearly defined service that people use, that service pretty much belongs in its own domain.

Comment: I would argue that the tag should be for the API and the _topics_ should be for "using x with Excel" and "using x with Perl"

Comment: so if I use Perl with Win32:OLE to edit Excel, shall it be `perl`, `excel`, or `win32ole` (which does not exist in **Documentation**)?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I would say it belongs in Excel, but we need multi language per example support to make this realistic.

Comment: Don't agree as there are lots of ways of using RESTful services from each language depending on the toolkit in use.